# How to pass non final variable inside of inner class

Tags: java, rx-java

I have following code. I need to pass the previous value (amount) for animating purposes, but I really couldn't understand this passing stuff.

I usually declare member variable, but I couldn't do it here since this is inside of a static method. How can I pass it inside of a function? Is my approach is wrong?

```
        puplic static void animate(TextView textView){
        double amount = 0.0;
            RxTextView
            .textChangeEvents(textView)
            .filter(t -> t.getText().toString().split("\\.")[1].length() == 2)
            .subscribe(e -> {
                stratAnimation(amount, e.getRawValue() / 100.0)
                amount = e.getRawValue() / 100.0;
            });
        }
```

Comment: Is this your entire class? What method are you trying to pass it into?

Comment: The code block looks a little bit weird. You have a value in `amount`, want to use it in the subscribe() block, but only when the `textChangeEvents()` fires, and when it does it should write the result back to the variable? How and when should that happen? On what timeline should all this work/run? While editing your question to answer these questions, please add the full static method. (And btw.: you can have static member variables as well)

Comment: You can use an `AtomicDouble()` to hold the value and `set()` the new value in the subscription.